# RabbitMQ Mirrored Queues on Multiple Clusters

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

Is it possible to use RabbitMQ HA using multiple(2) RabbitMQ clusters?

Here is my requirement:

We have 2 RabbitMQ clusters (each with 4 nodes). All the nodes in both the clusters will be using same Erlang cookie. So that, even though these 2 clusters are physically in separate locations, but will act as a single cluster with 8 nodes.

We are planning to use HAProxy to load balance both the clusters (8 nodes). Both publisher and consumer will be using this proxy to connect to the broker.

We would like to use mirrored queues for HA with ha-mode:exactly, ha-params:4, ha-sync-mode:automatic along with auto-heal for cluster_partition_handling.

Question:

1. In case of HA, is there a way we can specify to use 2 nodes from the first cluster and 2 nodes from the second cluster. As I understand, this can be done via policy ha-mode:nodes and use node names but that way it will always use the same node, can this setup be dynamic?
2. As both the clusters are very reliable, will it be the right approach to use auto-heal for cluster_partition_handling (in case of split brain)?
3. As per this "By default, queues within a RabbitMQ cluster are located on a single node (the node on which they were first declared). This is in contrast to exchanges and bindings, which can always be considered to be on all nodes.". Does this mean exchanges are mirrored by default? So when a message arrives at an exchange and that node goes down, will the message be available on the other exchange on the other node?

Answer (score 0):

> So that, even though these 2 clusters are physically in separate locations, but will act as a single cluster with 8 nodes.

Please do not do this. RabbitMQ clusters require *reliable* network connections with *low latency*. If your cluster crosses a WAN or availability zone your chance of having network partitions greatly increases. See [this section](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#overview-dealing-with-failure) of the docs for more information. You should use either the shovel or federation feature.

> Does this mean exchanges are mirrored by default? So when a message arrives at an exchange and that node goes down, will the message be available on the other exchange on the other node?

Yes and yes.

Comment: Our goal is HA, we have 2 physically separated data centers, connected over LAN with a network latency of 1ms. In this scenario, should we consider RabbitMQ federated exchange and federated queues or single cluster (with same cookie in both the data centers) with mirrored queues?